# Some applications on the Ubuntu dock/task bar are broken

Tags: taskbar

When clicking over some icons in the Ubuntu dock/task bar, they most of the time don't open and switch to drag mode, even when clicking once. Sometimes, just hovering over the icon causes the icon to switch to drag mode. 
I've also tried searching "applications always on drag mode" or something like that, but I couldn't get an answer for that problem. Does anyone know how to fix it?
Edit: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Which desktop environments / themes / shell extensions do you have installed?

Comment: Idk what these are, I probably have none.